# Is it possible to overlap the position to another position using Base adapter?

Tags: android

The first position or button ill set it as no margin and the following position has negative margin to overlap the first position.

The first position was ok but the other position that I set on negative margin looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhf4azrhtogwj89/sample3.PNG).

I want to make it like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dkhuto6bdwym9q/sample4.PNG).

```
public class ProductLineAdapter extends BaseAdapter{ 
private List<ProductLineInfo> productLineInfos;
private Context context;
private int prodCount;

public ProductLineAdapter(Context context,
        List<ProductLineInfo> productLineInfos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productLineInfos = productLineInfos;

    prodCount = productLineInfos.size();
    Log.d("Tabs", "List Name 1" + prodCount);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return productLineInfos.size();
}

@Override
public ProductLineInfo getItem(int position) {

    return productLineInfos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    String name = getItem(position).getName();
    int status = productLineInfos.size();
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.productline_name, parent, false);

         if (position == 0) {
         Button btn = new Button(context);
         btn.setText("sample");
         btn.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(
         R.drawable.tabs_pressed_state));
         ((ViewGroup) convertView).addView(btn);
         convertView.setTag(holder);

         } else if (position > 0) {
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         Button btn1 = new Button(context);
         btn1.setText("sample2");
         btn1.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(
         R.drawable.tabs_pressed_state));
         layoutParams.setMargins(-100, 0, 0, 0);
         btn1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
         ((ViewGroup) convertView).addView(btn1);
                      convertView.setTag(holder);
         }

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder {

    Button btn;
            Button btn1;  

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/blanktab_normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blanktab_normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blanktab_normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView 
    android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

1. I just used negative margin as shown above
2. Manipulate onClick of tabs (use [bringtofront](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29))

   1. on Click on Tab, make sure to populate the items under your list view.
   2. You can find a way to dynamically add views for your tabs.